# Spontaneous Server Errors During AngularJS $http calls

Tags: angularjs, http, laravel-5.1

I'm building an SPA in AngularJS served by a Laravel (5.1) backend. Of late I've been encountering an annoying error, a server 500 or code 0 error which is abit hard to explain how it comes but let me try to may be someone will understand the dental formula of my problem.

When i start my AngularJS controller, I make several server calls (via independent $http calls from services) to retrieve information i might later need in the controller. For example,

```
Functions.getGrades()
.then(function(response)
{
    $scope.grades = response.data;
});

Subjects.offered()
.then(function(response)
{
    $scope.subjects = response.data;
});
```

Later on i pass these variables (`grades` or `subjects`) to a service where they are used for processing. However, these functions are randomly returning code 500 server errors after they run, and sometimes returning status code 0 after running. This happens in a random way and it is hard for me to point out the circumstances leading to their popping up. This leaves me with frequent empty Laravel-ised error screens like the ones shown below. 
[image: error screen]

Anyone reading my mind?

Comment: Getting such an error is at first not a problem with the frontend. Have you checked your logs? Also you might switch on the debug mode for a bit more of error info http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors

Comment: The debug mode is set to true, may be i need to have a look at my logs. Was wondering could loading several independent $http calls have any such effect? Because when the error occurs and you refresh the page it will usually work ok

Comment: The $http calls should all finish, independent of one another. So "No, it should have no effect", unless you've programmed something which depends on kind of a side effect of another call. And that's what you have to find out. Your question is way to vague, to give any answer.

Comment: Yeah, i was also feeling the vagueness of the question and it took long to know how i should ask it, but your advice above to check in the Log files is the answer i needed exactly, plus some other tip that i found in another question, as my new answer reflects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a suggestion given in a comment above that I check my Laravel log files (located in `storage/logs/laravel.log`- Laravel 5.1), i found out that the main error most of these times was this one: `'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'' in ...`, plus another one that paraphrased something like `No valid encrypter found`. These were the key opener.

On reading another SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859601/whoops-looks-like-something-went-wrong-laravel-5-1), it said in part:

> I solved, sometimes laravel not read APP_KEY in .ENV. And returns a value "SomeRandomString" (default is defined in config / app.php), and have the error "key length is invalid", so the solution is to copy the value of APP_KEY, to the value 'key 'in config / app.php, that's all! I solved!

That was exactly the issue! When loading the DB params from the `.env` to `config/database.php`, Laravel was sometimes unable to read the environment variables and went for the fallback default fallback options (`forge` for DB name and username and `SomeRandomString` for the APP_KEY). So, to solve this i just did as advised: copied the APP_KEY in `.env` to the `config/app.php` and edited the default DB parameters to the actual DB name and username/password I'm using. Just that and i was free from pollution. Hope someone finds this helpful.